# THREE.js - Graphical Glitch with an imported model

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm experiencing a graphical glitch with an imported model while using JSONLoader.
I can't really explain it, you'll have to see it.
It may have something to do with the different materials and the camera POV.

You can find the plunk here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0VjHiGNmWFHxdoMWC3GV?p=info

JSONLoader part of the code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'tv.js',
        function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var tv = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
        glScene.add(tv);
} );
```

[a screenshot of the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK4xb.png)

Comment: Seems like depth buffer precision issue (z-fighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "glitch" you are referring to is due to z-fighting.

Your camera near plane is 0.01 and far plane is 20000. Small values of the near plane can lead to depth-sorting precision problems.

In your case, set your near plane to, 1 or 10.

ref: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision.

three.js r.81

Comment: After some experimenting, like adding planes and CSS3Dobjects in front of the model, this seems like the solution to my problem.

Comment: I am guessing that a near/far range of 0.1 to 10 makes the GL box 10 times bigger (or I should say, everything in it 10 times more smooshed) along Z, than with a near value of 1, in order to fit objects close to the camera. Is that right? It also seems that this distortion is a non-linear transform, because objects closer to the camera tend to have z-sorting glitches whereas far objects less or none. Is this right too?