# Possibly to prioritise drawing of objects in Threejs?

Tags: three.js

I am working on a CAD type system using threejs. I have thin objects next to other objects (think thin 2mm metal sheeting fixed to posts on a building measured in metres). When I am zoomed in it all looks fine. The objects do not intersect at all. As I zoom out the objects get smaller and I end up with cases where the post object 'glimmers' (sort of shows through) the metal sheet object as I rotate it around.

I understand it's the small numbers I am working with that is causing this effect. However, is there a way to set a priority such that one object (the metal sheeting) is more important than another object (post) so it doesn't get that sort of effect?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171817/three-js-graphical-glitch-with-an-imported-model/40186581#40186581) and try increasing the value of your near plane.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), where two fragments are so close in the given depth space that their z-values are within the margin of error that their true depths might get inverted.

The easiest way to resolve this is to reduce the scale of your depth buffer. This is controlled by the `near` and `far` properties on your `camera`. You'll need to play with the values to determine what works best for your senario. If you can minimize the distance between the planes, you'll have better luck avoiding z-fighting.

For example, if (as a loose estimate) the bounding sphere of your entire model has a diameter of `100`, then the distance between `near` and `far` need only be `100`. However, their values are set as the distance into camera space. So as you zoom out, and your camera moves further away, you should adjust the values to maintain the minimum distance between them. If your camera is at `z = 100`, then set `near = 50` and `far = 150`. When you pull your camera back to `z = 250`, then update `near = 200` and `far = 300`.

Another option is to use the [WebGLRenderer.logarithmicDepthBuffer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer) option. ([example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html))

**Edit:** There is one other cause: the faces of the shapes are actually co-planar. If two triangles are occupying the same space, then you're all but guaranteeing z-fighting.

The simple solution is to move one of the components such that the faces are no longer co-planar. You could also potentially apply a [polygonOffset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.polygonOffset) to the sheet metal material, but your use-case doesn't sound like that is appropriate.

Comment: I did read up on that. I started with near/far o 0.1/100 . I am treating one unit as 1 metre and drawing things to the millimetre so effectively 3 decimal places. I have changed the near/far to 1/50 and still have similar effect. I would not have thought the values were such that the logarithmicDepthBuffer would be required. I did try it but didn't make it any better.

Comment: @Jeff-SoftwareResults Are you using an Orthographic camera? Logarithmic depth buffer really only works with a Perspective camera. I've added more info on what could be causing the z-fighting, even if you're using the logarithmic depth buffer correctly.

Comment: Using perspective camera. I think the problem is I'm trying to draw really thin materials (metal sheeting) right next to large items (rafters)- not exactly co-planar but close. When I zoom out, the thin bits almost end up transparent and the large objects 'shine' through. I have tried offset the sheeting object from the rafter objects and it only sort of helps. I can't offset them too much because when I zoom in it doesn't look right having the sheeting floating away from the rafter. I'll try the polygonOffset when I get the chance see if it does help at all.

Comment: 0.1 as near is still going to pull most of the precision towards the near plane. Even trying with something like 1 may help.

Comment: @pailhead I don't think I made that point clear enough. I'll add a little more detail.

Comment: I’d investigate polygon offset here a bit, I think it could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from the title, it is possible to prioritize drawing orders with.

```
myMesh.renderOrder = 5
myOtherMesh.renderOrder = 7
```

It is then possible to apply different depth effects, turn off the test etc.

Another way is to group objects with, layers. Set the appropriate layer mask on the camera and then render (multiple times).

```
myMesh.layers.set(5)

camera.layers.set(1)
renderer.render(scene,camera)
camera.layers.set(5)
renderer.render(scene,camera)
```

Comment: The renderOrder I have already tried and didn't make any difference. The layer one I would have to try. Haven't seen that approach before.

Comment: Just rearranging things won’t actually help. However you could try drawing certain things without depth tests for example. It’s hard to tell without looking at your scene.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn’t actually solve your problem, but if you find a solution that does rely on specific render orders, you can control it with three.js